# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{\ln(n+1)}{1+\ln(n+1)}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\ln(n+1)}{1+\ln\left(n\right)}}-1\right).$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I came across the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ while computing an upper bound, where  $$a_n =  \sqrt{\frac{\ln\left(n+1\right)}{1+\ln\left(n+1\right)}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\ln\left(n+1\right)}{1+\ln\left(n\right)}}-1\right).$$
I am struggling to decide whether this sum converges. Graphically the summand goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, but the sum seems to grow extremely slowly, like $\sqrt{\ln(\ln(n))}$, but all of this is just a hunch from the graphs I have plotted. I am not sure how to prove whether this sum diverges or not. I tried comparison tests with $b_n = \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$, $\alpha = \frac{7}{6}, \frac{5}{4}$, but they failed for large values of $n$.

Comment: To be slow, it is !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that
$$
\sqrt {\frac{{1 + \log (n + 1)}}{{1 + \log (n)}}}  - 1 = \sqrt {1 + \frac{{\log (n + 1) - \log n}}{{1 + \log (n)}}}  - 1 \sim \sqrt {1 + \frac{1}{{n\log (n)}}}  - 1 \sim \frac{1}{{2n\log (n)}}
$$
and
$$
\sqrt {\frac{{\log (n + 1)}}{{1 + \log (n + 1)}}}  \sim 1
$$
as $n\to +\infty$. Thus,
$$
a_n  \sim \frac{1}{{2n\log (n)}}
$$
as $n\to +\infty$, whence the series diverges by the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) (since $\sum \frac{1}{{n\log (n)}}$ diverges by the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) or the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)).

Comment: aah, thank you so much.

Comment: Congrats for hitting 25k

Answer (score 3):

$$a_n =  \sqrt{\frac{\log\left(n+1\right)}{1+\log\left(n+1\right)}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\log\left(n+1\right)}{1+\log\left(n\right)}}-1\right)$$
Parforming a series expansion for large values of $n$
$$a_n=\frac{\sqrt{\log (n)}}{2 n (1+\log (n))^{3/2}}\left(1- \frac{(\log (n)+2) (2 \log (n)-1)}{4 n \log (n) (\log (n)+1)} +O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$$
$$a_n\sim\frac{\sqrt{\log (n)}}{2 n (1+\log (n))^{3/2}}$$

$$I_m=\int_1^m \frac{\sqrt{\log (n)}}{2 n (1+\log (n))^{3/2}}\,dn$$ $$I_m=\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\log (m)}{\log
   (m)+1}}\right)-\sqrt{\frac{\log (m)}{\log (m)+1}}$$ which tends to $\infty$.

**Edit**

Computing the sums up to $n=10^4$ and using a totally empirical model
$$\sum_{n=1}^p a_n=-a+b \big[\log(p)\big]^c$$
with $R^2=0.9999999925$ (adjusted), the results
$$\begin{array}{|llll}
\hline
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std Error} &
   \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 1.37588 & 0.01341 & \{1.34927,1.40249\} \\
 b & 1.41467 & 0.01262 & \{1.38962,1.43973\} \\
 c & 0.19668 & 0.00126 & \{0.19417,0.19918\} \\
\end{array}$$ with a maximum absolute error equal to $3.462\times 10^{-4}$ and a mean absolute error equal to $4.766\times 10^{-5}$.

**Update**

After @Gary's comment
$$\sum_{n=1}^p a_n=a+b\,\log(\log(p))$$ leads, with $R^2=0.9999912$, to the following results
$$\begin{array}{l|lll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std Error} &
   \text{Confidence Interval} \\
\hline
 a & 0.40146 & 0.00060 & \{0.400,0.403\} \\
 b & 0.07634 & 0.00127 & \{0.074,0.079\} \\
\end{array}$$
with  a mean absolute error equal to $1.455\times 10^{-3}$.

Comment: Try the scheme $a\log\log(p)+b$ instead.

Comment: @Gary. Done, Sir ! Cheers :-)